# Socket.io doesn't sending event in group immediately in new created room

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I got a problem with sending events to new logged-in users. I created a "join" event, which is pushing the user, to an array, then emitting new action 'update-users' to all users which are inside one room.

```
const { addUser, getAllUsers } = require('./users');

const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

const port = 3000;

const connected = {};
let connectedUsers = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('join', ({ name }) => {
    const { error } = addUser({ id: socket.id, name }); // This method is pushing "User" to array. If error is occured, returning error.
    connected[name] = socket.id;

    socket.join('login-room');

    setTimeout(() => {
      io.in('login-room').emit('update-users', getAllUsers());
    }, 400);
  });

});

http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('connected to port 3000');
});
```

So as you see I have "setTimeout" here, with this setTimeout everything works fine. But if I remove it - it's not working. Seems like we need some time to join this socket to his room then send an event. Do you have any ideas how can I improve it?

Comment: You should post the content of `addUser`and `getAllUsers` methods, I guess you have asynchronous code where the promises are not corretly handled, hence the need of a `setTimeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that it takes some time to join the room. However, `setTimeout` is a bad solution, since the time it will take to join the room is unpredictable. The socked might also fail to join the room.

The good news is that `socket.join()` is an asynchronous method and takes a callback as a second argument. So use it like this:

```
socket.join('login-room', () => {
  io.in('login-room').emit('update-users', getAllUsers());
);
```

@l-faros is also right in that your `getAllUsers()` method might be asynchronous, so you would have another problem of the same kind there.

I am afraid you might have a JS knowledge gap which I advise to fill in by doing some reading on JavaScript asynchronicity, callbacks, promises and all that (Google is your friend).

Comment: Tried in this way, it's not working :s Still user list is not updated...
`
  socket.on('join', ({ name }) => {
    addUser({ id: socket.id, name });
    connected[name] = socket.id;

    socket.join('login-room', () => {
      io.in('login-room').emit('update-users', getAllUsers());
    });
  });
`

Comment: Then, as already suggested in the comments, `addUser` is most likely an asynchronous function. Please post the code to that and `getAllUsers`.